# Docusign Tabs - May not be present

Tags: docusignapi

I get this error

```
 ANCHOR_TAB_STRING_NOT_FOUND
```

When I submit my document to Docusign for embedded signing. Trouble is, not every document will have every possible tag on it. A different system generates the PDF and its only sent to Docusign if the person decides to digitally sign it. So by the time my api script gets called to create the document, I dont know what tags are on there.

So how do I get around this? Any easier way than storing tag data into a database when the PDF is generated and pulling it later? Trying to not do any docusign stuff unless needed. Dont want to waste space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So basically you are submitting a document to DocuSign where you don't know what's in the document- in this case you don't know if the anchors you are trying to set are in it.  The DocuSign platform is acting correctly in that you if you specify anchor strings in a request and you don't have `IgnoreIfNotPresent` set to true and those strings are not found then it will return an error.

I think you're best option is to scan the document bytes for the anchor string sequence(s) you are using BEFORE you make the request to DocuSign, and have your code dynamically populate only the anchors that are actually found in the document.

Otherwise if you simply don't know anything about the document you're feeding into DocuSign then you can set `IgnoreIfNotPresent` to `true` to avoid the error.

Comment: I decided when the document is made to write to a database

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the AnchorTab Schema has a IgnoreIfNotPresent value.

https://www.docusign.com/p/APIGuide/APIGuide.htm#Sending%20Group/AnchorTab.htm

I'd assume that if the system you're using sets this value to true then this error would resolve itself.

Comment: So there is no way to have this IgnoreIfNotPresent be set at the template level? It would have to be down at the tabs level?